# New list containing list + string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

How do i make a new list containing existing list + a new string?

```
Const1 = "1000"
Const2 = "2000"
Const3 = "3000"
CONST_LIST = [Const1, Const2]
CONST_LIST_NEW = [CONST_LIST] + Const3 #Nogo
print CONST_LIST_NEW
```

Wish output.....
['1000', '2000', '3000']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between append vs. extend list methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the error the interpreter is giving you, you will see there is a TypeError: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`.

So you need to conecatenate two lists, and as CONT_LIST is already a list, there is no need for square brackets around it. But your string needs to be in a new list, so just put `[Const3]`

Finally it looks like this:

```
Const1 = "1000"
Const2 = "2000"
Const3 = "3000"
CONST_LIST = [Const1, Const2]
CONST_LIST_NEW = CONST_LIST + [Const3]
print CONST_LIST_NEW
```

Comment: Thx. But isnt that gonna give this outout? (['1000', '2000'], ['3000'])

Comment: For anyone else wondering, the output of `(['1000', '2000'], ['3000'])` is given when you leave `[CONT_LIST]`. A good explanation can be seen in @Chris comment in the question above.